# How to configure Post build tasks in Hudson?

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-plugin-batch-task

Hi I am using Hudson for source code management. I am able to correctly download the required code from my feature branch and successfully build it.
But I also require to trigger an .exe file once my build has been successful which I am unable to figure out.

Do I have to use some plugin or there is some other way? If it is a plugin please specify how to set up.

Additional Details: I can trigger the exe perfectly from the command prompt but when I write the same command in the Build step of my job, I just get a "Finished: Success" message but not exe has been triggered

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post build task plugin : http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Post+build+task.

To add this plugin in your project, just search for 'post build' on plugin's search page and install it.

After that you can configure on your job's page. It will appear a checkbox with this label: 'Post build task'.